# how to show multiple polyline using openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am getting more than one path at a time and one coordinate in a second for each path. I want to create polyline for each path which I am getting dynamically. I tried but working well  for single path and not for multiple.

```
var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer");
        map.addLayer(lineLayer);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));

        var linePoints = [];

        socketConnection.on('date', function (responseData) {
            marker.clearMarkers();
            $.each(responseData, function (deviceName, deviceCoordinate) {
                var mapLatitudeLongitude = deviceCoordinate.split(',');
                var markersLongitudeLatitude = new OpenLayers.LonLat(mapLatitudeLongitude[1], mapLatitudeLongitude[0).transform(projectionFrom, projectionTo,0);
                map.panTo(markersLongitudeLatitude);
                var myCord = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(mapLatitudeLongitude[1],mapLatitudeLongitude[0]).transform(projectionFrom, projectionTo,0);
                marker.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(markersLongitudeLatitude));
                linePoints.push(myCord);
            })
          var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(linePoints);
var style = { 
strokeColor: '#ff0000', 
strokeOpacity: 0.5,
strokeWidth: 2
};

var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
```

Help me in drawing multiple polyline.

Comment: Are you talking about using a MultiLineString? A MultiLineString takes an array of LineStrings in its constructor. If so, you would have to have an array of linePoints to push each new point to, and you would need to know which device it was coming from, so the new point went into the correct LineString.

Comment: yes I am using Openlayers first time. Can you please show me an example how to make above code working. ?

Comment: Sure, bit busy with work and world cup, but I will try and do this soon.